# Change pages on tkinter and remove the previous page's content

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to build an investment calculator app using tkinter.
I used these 2 videos as a guidance:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=95tJO7XJlko

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URozV-5yL-g

If you execute the program it works fine.
However, I have some issues:

1. if I clcik on the button ABOUT, a message shows as it should (see image 1 attached).
   However if I click on another button and then go back and click on the ABOUT button,
   the message appears in a frame, which come from the layout of the other
   buttons (see image 2 attached).
   If, by any chance, you are familiar with tkinter, could you please help me fix this?
2. Also, in the code I put a function inside another function as otherwise I had to declare
   some global variable.
   However, I am not happy with this solution. Maybe you have some helpful advice.

This is my code. I just included the one regarding the BOND and ABOUT button as otherwise the code would have been too long.

```
## import maths and tkinter module.


import math
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk



def bond_page():
    bond_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame)
    ##    define label content
    lb = tk.Label(bond_frame)
    lb.pack()
    bond_frame.pack(pady=20)
    
    # Define labels and entry boxes
    amount_label = Label(main_frame, text = 'Loan Amount')
    amount_entry = Entry(main_frame, font = ('Helvetica', 18))

    interest_label = Label(main_frame, text = 'Interest rate')
    interest_entry = Entry(main_frame, font = ('Helvetica', 18))

    term_label = Label(main_frame, text = 'Terms (months)')
    term_entry = Entry(main_frame, font = ('Helvetica', 18))
    
    # Put labels and entry boxes on screen
    amount_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    amount_entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    interest_label.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    interest_entry.grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady=40)

    term_label.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    term_entry.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

    def bond():
        if amount_entry.get() and interest_entry.get() and term_entry.get():
            ## Convert entry boxes into numbers
            years = int(term_entry.get())
            months = years * 12
            rate = float(interest_entry.get())
            loan = int(amount_entry.get())
        ##  Calculate the loan
        ##  Monthly interest rate
            monthly_rate = rate / 100 / 12
        ## Get our payment
            payment = monthly_rate * loan / (1 - (1 + monthly_rate)** (-months))
        ## Output payment to the screen
            payment_label.config(text=f'Your monthly payment: ${payment:.2f}')
                       
        else:
            payment_label.config(text='Hey! You forgot to enter something!')
    
    ## Button

    calculate_button = Button( text='Calculate Payment', command=bond)
    calculate_button.place(x=270, y=350)

    ## Output label
    payment_label = Label(root, text='', font=('Helvetica', 18))
    payment_label.place(x=270, y=400)
    


def about_page():
    about_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame)
    ##    define label content
    lb = tk.Label(about_frame, text='''Hello, this is my first project.
I used these two videos as a starting point,
and then I did all by myself.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=95tJO7XJlko

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URozV-5yL-g

''', font=('Bold', 11))
    lb.pack()
    about_frame.pack(pady=20)       



def hide_indicators():
    bond_indicate.config(bg='#c3c3c3')
    about_indicate.config(bg='#c3c3c3')
    
    

def hide_pages():
    for frame in main_frame.winfo_children():
        frame.destroy()
        

def indicate(lb, page):
    hide_indicators()
    lb.config(bg='#158aff')
    hide_pages()
    page()

    

root = Tk()
root.title('Investment Calculator APP')
root.iconbitmap('')
root.geometry('700x500')

## setting options frames
options_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#c3c3c3')
options_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
## resize options frames
options_frame.pack_propagate(False)
## set height and width
options_frame.configure(width=270, height=500)

## main frame
main_frame = tk.Frame(root, highlightbackground='black',
                      highlightthickness=2)
main_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
main_frame.pack_propagate(False)
main_frame.configure(height=500, width=500)


## create buttons

## bond
bond_button = tk.Button(options_frame, text='BOND', font=('Bold', 15),
                        fg='#158aff', bd=0, bg='#c3c3c3', command=lambda: indicate(bond_indicate, bond_page))
bond_button.place(x=10, y=50)

bond_indicate = tk.Label(options_frame, text='', bg='#c3c3c3')
bond_indicate.place(x=3, y=50, width=5, height=40)

## about
about_button = tk.Button(options_frame, text='ABOUT', font=('Bold', 15),
                        fg='#158aff', bd=0, bg='#c3c3c3',  command=lambda: indicate(about_indicate, about_page))
about_button.place(x=10, y=200)

about_indicate = tk.Label(options_frame, text='', bg='#c3c3c3')
about_indicate.place(x=3, y=200, width=5, height=40)


## end program
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 solutions for you, for both of your problems.

**Problem #1 - about window not working properly**
I would suggest you replace `tk.Frame` with a `tk.Toplevel` object - this seems to work most of the time. Here is an example:

```
def about_page():
    about_frame = tk.Toplevel(root) # You will need to move the root declaration above this.
    about_frame.title("About")
    about_frame.geometry("WIDTHxHEIGHT")
    Label(about_frame, text='''YOUR TEXT HERE''').pack()
```

Create the window by calling the method `about_page()`. When you need to remove the window, use `window.destroy()`, with window as your window variable.

**Problem #2 - Ugly function in function**
This is an easy fix! `global` in python allows you to modify variables created outside of a function (but only in **THAT** function, bear with me). That said, you will need to add some declarations for your variables. That would look like this:

```
amount_entry = None
interest_entry = None
term_entry = None
```

In your `bond_page()` function (which I would also recommend setting up as a `Tk.toplevel()`), you need to add this to your function start:

```
def bond_page():
    global amount_entry
    global interest_entry
    global term_entry
    # Rest of code here...
```

You can now seperate `bond()` and `bond_page()`. `bond()` would also need to have `global` in the function name:

```
def bond():
    global amount_entry
    global interest_entry
    global term_entry
    # Rest of code here...
```

I also would personally recommend you don't follow YouTube tutorials. Some can be pretty outdated or give bad advice. That's my opinion though, you do what you want!

I hope this helps! If I need to provide anything else, let me know.

**EDIT #1: Destroying main window**
While I personally wouldn't recommend this, you can always do it! I would recommend still allowing the main window to be used, because (to me) it feels awkward to have only one window open at a time.

I would recommend moving all of your main setup code into a separate function when you do this and globaling all variables defined before (like the above code).

You can simply `global main` and then run `main.destroy()` to destroy your main window. Then, when the user is done, you'll need to run all of that setup code again, then do `about_frame.destroy()`.

To handle opening up main window again when the user is done, you'll need to add this line to your about_frame code:

```
about_frame.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", setupMainWindow) # Replace setupMainWindow with the code that sets up your main function...
```

That's all! To reiterate, you can easily destroy your main object. Simply do this:

```
global mainWindow
mainWindow.destroy()
```

But you'll also need to handle when the user wants to close the about window, so move all the code that sets up mainWindow into a function, global all the variables, and set up mainWindow. Then, when you want to close about_frame, use this line while setting it up to handle closing:

```
about_frame.protocol("WM_DESTROY_WINDOW", mainWindowSetup) # Again, replace mainWindowSetup with another function name...
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if I can provide more.

Comment: Thank you, Sam. I fixed the global variables!  but still struggling with the other issue. This is how my code looks like now:            
def about_page():
    about_frame = tk.Toplevel(root)
    about_frame.title("About")
    about_frame.geometry("300x400")
    Label(about_frame, text='''YOUR TEXT HERE''').pack()             However when I run it creates another window that pops up, but still the main one behaves the same as I described. Could you please also give me more hints on how to use window() to kill the about page? Thank you for your time and help

Comment: @MarkusPe Sorry for being busy! Sure, lemme check.

Comment: @MarkusPe Sure, I suppose you can do that - it is kind of annoying, when the user opens the about window you'll need to reset main all over again, but you can do it. I'll update my answer now.

Comment: Edits applied! Hope it helps :)